# How to use torch RNN and LSTM packages and are they necessary?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, torch

I have come across this brilliant [site](http://peterroelants.github.io/posts/rnn_implementation_part01/) where I finally understood BPTT for RNN's and want to implement it. The code is given in python but I want to implement it in torch using lua. I have understood the code and have translated most of it to lua with torch functions. However, I have often come across packages for torch on github like [this](https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn). How can we use these packages? If we were to use them, would we not need to type even a single line of code? Isn't it better if I first completely code the RNN myself to understand and then go on to the packages?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn, implement from scratch. If you want to apply, just use some packages: the amount of tweaking the latter require depends on the package and your application.